# Get Records other than unique in a DataTable using asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, datatable

I want to store Unique Records and other than unique records in two different `datatable`.

I have implemented the logic of getting Unique Records in a `datatable` but I am confused on how to get the records other than unique ones.

Below is the code which I tried.

```
dtExcelRows = dtExcelRows
              .AsEnumerable()
              .GroupBy(r => new 
                            { 
                              Col1 = r.Field<String>("SAP-ID") 
                            })
              .Select(g =>
                        {
                          var rowss = g.First();
                          return rowss;
                        })
             .CopyToDataTable();
             dtExcelRows.AcceptChanges();
```

The above code gives me the Unique Records. Please suggest me on how to get the Other records in other DataTable.

Comment: So, you want remaining duplicate entries in other DataTable?

Comment: @SelvaTS : yes, I want that duplicate entries in another datatable...

Comment: Firstly, reassigning `dtExcelRows` means you threw away those rows.

Comment: @NetMage : So will I be able to get those rows or not ??

Comment: Only if you get them first. Your code doesn't get the unique records, it gets the first record of each group of records, some of which may be unique and some of which may not, so what do you mean by other records? The records not in the query?

Comment: Also, why is your code so (inefficiently) verbose? `GroupBy(r => r.Field<string>("SAP-ID").Select(g => g.First())` is all that you need for the middle of it.

Comment: @NetMage:yes, my code might not be well maintained. Please give me your final piece of code, so that I can try

Comment: Can you answer: exactly what do you mean by "other records"? The records excluded from your query?

Answer (score 0):

We can you the `Skip()` extension to get the remaining items other than unique values. Try something like below,

You are getting the First() value from the grouped items in your code. So we can skip the first one and get the remained items.

```
var duplicateItems = dataTable
              .AsEnumerable()
              .GroupBy(r => new
              {
                  Col1 = r.Field<String>("SAP-ID")
              })
              .Select(g => g.Skip(1)).SelectMany(x => x).CopyToDataTable();

            duplicateItems.AcceptChanges();
```

[C# Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hOZW6Y) for this.

Comment: you are taking that in a variable, right ? is it possible to take it in a datatble

Comment: getting error as `The source contains no DataRows.`

Comment: @BNN Have you checked whether your data has duplicate entries? Check the fiddle. It is working fine. Also the result in a `DataTable`.

Comment: Yes, I have it, coz I am purposely uploading duplicate data for testing purpose

Comment: @BNN I have tried with some other data and it is working fine for me. Please check your `GroupBy` expression.